# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n}e^{-a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers which diverges to $+\infty$. Then when can we say that the following series converges? $$\sum_{n\ge 1}e^{-a_n}$$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `\large` command is at best distracting.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Did.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing: it may converge or diverge:

- divergence: $a_n:=\log n$;
- convergence: $a_n=2\log n$.

The updated question reduces to the following: if $b_n$ is a sequence of positive numbers converging to $0$, when does the series $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}b_n$ converge, which is too broad.

Comment: I think you may tell him the range of $a_n$ for which it diverges and for which it converges.

Comment: @WilliamHilbert And how would one define this "range"?

Comment: @Did: It seems to me that the series converges for all $a_n$ $\geq$ $2 \ln n$. Probably it's enough to answer your question.

Comment: Is it possible to tell when the series will converge even if the sequence $a_n$ diverges? Maybe I'll update in my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: Davide's example clearly answers your question. Isn't it?

Comment: @WilliamHilbert This can hardly define a "range" since the series converges for some sequences such that $a_n\lt2\log n$ for every $n$. Even more annoyingly, it also converges for some sequences such that $a_n\lt\log n$ for infinitely many $n$...

Comment: @Did: Can you give at least one example?

Comment: @WilliamHilbert An example of what?

Comment: @Did: An example or proof supporting your previous comment.

Comment: @WilliamHilbert Davide's example does not answer my updated question.

Comment: @WilliamHilbert Oh, I see, we have a skeptic here... Well,  for the first assertion, you might try $a_n=\frac32\log n$ for every $n$, and for the second assertion, $a_n=2\log n$ when $n$ is not a square and $a_n=\frac34\log n$ when $n$ is a square.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: I thought that the sequence $a_n$ $=$ $2 \ln n$ diverges and so it answers your question. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @WilliamHilbert, I want to find a general condition (if it exists) for a diverging sequence $\{a_n\}$ for which the series converges. $a_n=2\log n$ is just one example of that, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

A series can either converge, diverge or oscillate. A sequence is said to be convergent if it tends to a finite quantity. In this case, if a1=1, a2=2 ... , it converges to 1/(e-1)