# Convergence of a series of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{u_k\}_{k \geq 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $u_k \to +\infty$.
For $t>0$, consider the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} e^{-u_k t}.$$
I am wondering if there always exists a $t>0$ such that this series converges (pointwise) ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770234/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-ne-a-n?rq=1

Comment: Thanks but it does not answer my question. In my question, $u_k$ is fixed, and $t$ may depend on this sequence. In the post you linked to me, $t=1$ is universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't think so. For $k$ large enough set $u_{k} = \ln (ln k)$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k = N}^{\infty}e^{-t(\ln{(\ln k})} = \sum_{k = N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln{k})^{t}}
\end{equation*}
which is divergent for all $t > 0$ by the Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And do you know if there is a general result on the radius of convergence for such series ?

Comment: This might be relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks !